# LibreOffice does not recalculate sums

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a Calc sheet in LibreOffice (6.0.3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04).

In one field I have the formula `=sum(D2:D85)`.

Then I changed some values in the range D2 to D85, but the sum was not recalculated. If I write the same formula into another field, it shows the new correct sum.

I know that there is an option somewhere as to when formulas should be recalculated, but I can't find it. (Of course I could delete the field with the wrong sum and rewrite it, but I want a general solution to avoid errors.)

Answer (score 2):

You can enable this option in: Tools -> Cell Contents -> Autocalculate

edit per OP: in my LibreOffice, there is no Tools -> Cell Contents. Instead I found Autocalculate at 'Data -> Calculate -> Autocalculate'.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the hint to look for 'autocalculate'. However in my LibreOffice, there is no Tools -> Cell Contents. Instead I found it at 'Data -> Calculate -> Autocalculate'.

Comment: There is still a problem: 'Autocalculate' was already activated. I found a similar bug report that after inserting a cell in a horizontal row the sum of the cells in the row has not been update. I had my data in a column where I had deleted some rows before. I will see if this behavior is reproducible. (The mentioned bug should be corrected since V6.0.)

Answer (score 0):

I still have this problem with Libreoffce calc in 2022, nearly four years after this was posted.

There is no reliable fix for this, and the above solutions do not work 100%. This software is not fit purpose and cannot be relied upon to give consistent and correct calculations. Sadly I have to go back to using mainstream paid software for personal business needs.

Why bother?!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1111846)

Comment: "There's no way to do this reliably, other than using better software" is an answer.